# How do focus TextInput on ComponentDidMount?

Tags: react-native

I use:

```
ComponentDidMount(){
  this.foca()
}

foca = () => {
  this.refs.edit.focus()
}

<TextInput
  ref='edit'
  style={{height:60, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', borderRadius:10}}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({busca: text})}
  onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: this.state.busca})}
/>
```

But it not works...

I like to set a focus on my TextInput when show the screen

Answer (score 9):

Just add this property to your TextInput component
[autofocus](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autofocus)

```
<TextInput  autoFocus={true} />
```